# From 5,2,20,6,6 to B,A,D,C,C

Tags: vb.net

There are 5 numbers in an Array. I want to change and sort them with letters from less to more.

For example:

```
Dim Fg() As Byte = {31, 4, 1, 2, 4}

Dim Fc() as String
```

What I want is:

```
31, 4, 1, 2, 4   >>>    Fc = {D, C, A, B, C}

1, 2, 3, 4, 5    >>>    Fc = {A, B, C, D, E}

5, 4, 3, 2, 1    >>>    Fc = {E, D, C, B, A}

2, 2, 1, 3, 3    >>>    Fc = {B, B, A, C, C}
```

etc...

How can I do this in Visual Basic .NET?

Comment: Can you try writing it yourself first? and then we can help you wherever you get stuck or it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Why does C = 4 in your first example but 3 everywhere else?  Was that on purpose?

Comment: @sous2817 the letter represent the ordering inside the array ; A for smallest to E for greatest ; 4 in the first example and 3 in the others are ranked third item so they are mapped to C

Comment: @Sehnsucht Makes more sense now, but I think you're good for figuring it out.

Comment: Dear sstan, I had done this code before but my computer break down and all my codes gone away. So I'm trying re-code this application again but I cant this time.. This part was hardest to me, so I wanted an help. Thank you.

Comment: "help" means you give it a go first and we pitch in on parts that dont work correctly.  You are just asking for us to write your code for you.

Comment: Plutonix, you are right, I'm wrong. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

i would try to load the number in a sortedlist and then get the index of each value and convert it to a letter by adding the index to the ascii code (starting with 65).